# Parsing a XML file with name Space

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Ok, this is driving me nuts, i have an XML file which represents a call detail records which has a layout of and as note it uses a namespace

```
<File>
  <FileHeader>
  </FileHeader>
  <CDRs>
     <Call>
     </Call>
     <Call>
     </Call>
  </Cdrs>
  <FileFooter>
  </FileFooter>
</File>
```

i have no problem loading the file but   when i try

`Dim thisNode As XmlNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("meta:File/FileHeader", nsmgr)`

i always get nothing. but if i use

`xmlnodes2 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("FileHeader")`

i can access my nodes inside just fine like this

```
xmlHeader = xmlnodes2(0)
Dim seqnum As String = ""
Dim EquipmentType As String = xmlHeader.SelectSingleNode("meta:EquipmentType", nsmgr).InnerText
Dim EquipmentId As String = xmlHeader.SelectSingleNode("meta:EquipmentId", nsmgr).InnerText
Dim CreateTime As String = xmlHeader.SelectSingleNode("meta:CreateTime", nsmgr).InnerText

Debug.WriteLine("---------------------Debug File Header----------------------")
Debug.WriteLine(seqnum & " - " & EquipmentType & " - " & EquipmentId & " - " & CreateTime)
Debug.WriteLine(xmlHeader.OuterXml)
```

And here is what the Start of my xml File looks like so i am wondering what am i missing here ?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <File xmlns="http://www.metaswitch.com/cfs/billing/V1.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" compatibility="2">
 <FileHeader seqnum="23997">
 <EquipmentType>Metaswitch CFS</EquipmentType>
 <EquipmentId></EquipmentId>
 <CreateTime>1491092100003</CreateTime>
 </FileHeader>
 <CDRs>.....`
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML. (I'd also suggest adding the vb.net tag to the question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was that i did not understand i need to specify the the namespace prefix at each level so to make this work i had to use

```
Dim thisNode As XmlNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("meta:File/meta:FileHeader", nsmgr)
```